# Wrong output being displayed on the window even when the console is showing the matching values from the database

Tags: c#, .net

[I have attached a screenshot of my output screen .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrlrb.png)My code is giving me an unusual flaw.It is a Login program that I am working on.And the problem is that when I debug & run the code entering the correct inputs to the specified fields exactly similar to the entries in the database. The console is properly fetching the right values but the output I get is an unsuccessful Login.I do not understand why is this happening could someone guide me!
`

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       String s1 = textBox1.Text;
       String s2 = textBox2.Text;

       SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True");
       String sql = ("select Userid,Password from reg where Userid='" + s1 + "' and Password='" + s2 + "' ");
       cnn.Open();

       String userid="";
       String password="";

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn);
       SqlDataReader reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader();



        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
          while(reader.Read())
          {
              userid = reader.GetString(0);
              password = reader.GetString(1);

              Console.WriteLine(userid);
              Console.WriteLine(password);
          }
```

The If statement checks if the entered userid & password are similar to the existing userid passwrd in the DB.

```
       if((s1.Equals(userid)) && (s2.Equals(password)))
          {

               MessageBox.Show("LOGIN SUCCESSFULLY DONE>>");
          }

          else
          {
               MessageBox.Show("LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL ....");
          }
      }
```

Comment: Have you looked into EntityFramework to handle you database needs rather than raw ADO?

Comment: So either `s1` doesn't match `userid`, or `s2` doesn't match `password`. Inspect your variables. Watch closely for whitespace. Also don't store plaintext passwords, don't do string concatenation for SQL queries, properly name your variables and so on.

Comment: Try to `Trim` text box values and then check

Comment: I would rather say to trim values from DB. Or maybe it has to do with culture info?

Comment: @CodeCaster If not string concatenation then what other alternative should I try out for this Query?

Comment: Parameterized queries. But that won't solve the problem you're having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be there are additional spaces into strings? Try using Trim()

```
String s1 = textBox1.Text.Trim();
String s2 = textBox2.Text.Trim();
```

and

```
userid = reader.GetString(0).Trim();
password = reader.GetString(1).Trim();
```

Do you known that just one record is returned from database?

Comment: Could you please explain me what that Trim() actually did!!

Comment: `Trim` removes trailing spaces from the beginning and end of a string, you can specify `TrimStart` to trim the beginning of the string, and you can use `TrimEnd` to trim the end of the string

Comment: Trim() remove spaces from both ends of string. The reason of your problem can be fixed lenght of database fields.

Comment: It could be to do with Micosoft's implementation of the SQL standard  when checking for equality, both strings left and right of the equality operator have to be padded to have the same length . The UserId or Password field may containing trailing space(s). You could test this by replacing the two = in the SQL statement with LIKE. A more detailed explanation here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/sql-server-auto-trim-of-varchar-value-in-equal-comparison-but-not-like-compariso

Comment: i have used varchar of length 50 is that causing these trailing spaces? And when you say string which string is it-the one in the database or the string I enter in the textbox

Comment: Actually you can check it byself, print out the strings before trimming like this: Console.WriteLine(":" + userid + ":"); and look what is printed between this ":".